# Running AppleScript on Python : "Syntax Error: Expected end of line but found end of script."

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, applescript

When I run the following code I keep getting this:

> Syntax Error: Expected end of line but found end of script error

I'm relatively new to AppleScript.
This is my first try doing this and haven't been able to implement this yet. Let me know if I am missing anything, or if there is an alternative way to do this. The few similar examples I have seen have been single line applescripts, so I was wondering if that is the problem.

```
import subprocess

def chooseFile():                                   
    args = []
    args.append('osascript')
    args.append('-e')
    args.append('tell application "System Events"')
    args.append('delay 1')
    args.append('keystroke "G" using {command down,  shift down}')
    args.append('delay 2')
    args.append('keystroke "/Users/username/Desktop/folder/image.jpg"')
    args.append('delay 1')
    args.append('keystroke return')
    args.append('delay 1')
    args.append('keystroke return')
    args.append('end tell')    
    subprocess.call(args)
    
chooseFile()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `-e` for each line of your script according to [this](https://ss64.com/osx/osascript.html).
For example:

```py
args.extend(["-e",'tell application "System Events"'])
```

Comment: Great! Got it to work. I tried doing this before, but was basically adding an extra "-e" at the end after "end tell". Thanks.